# Spinner in dialog : NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-spinner

Good Day i am using spinner inside dialog and it generating

```
Error msg- ` java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference at com.example.amw51.ygeianapp.Activity.AwardActivity.showAddItem(AwardActivity.java:259)
```

Java code

```
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.job_add_detials_layout);
Spinner   jobSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.select_job_spinner);
 jobSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.select_job_spinner);
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("Android");
                list.add("Java");
                list.add("Spinner Data");
                list.add("Spinner Adapter");
                list.add("Spinner Example");

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                        (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);

                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource
                        (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                jobSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
 dialog.show();
```

XML Layout

```
 <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/select_job_spinner"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

i have searched everywhere but didnt find any proper solution .
                            `

Comment: if spinner is under dialog ui use `dialog.findViewById(R.id.select_job_spinner)`

Comment: i updated with dialog.findViewById but i am getting same error

Comment: probably does belong to a different layout. Should not be hard to fix it and you should find many examples on stackoverflow itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are **not**  retrieving `Spinner` from dialog itself. You should be performing `dialog.findViewById()` instead of ordinary `findViewById()`:

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.job_add_detials_layout);
dialog.create();
Spinner jobSpinner = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.select_job_spinner);
// init spinner
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Still same error

Comment: It's weird, but try to perform `findViewById` after `dialog.show()`.